# Postgres: Need to select keywords as separate array values

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Datatype:

```
id: int4
keywords: text
objectivable_id: int4
```

Postgres version: `PostgreSQL 9.5.3`

Business_objectives table:

```
id                 keywords                   objectivable_id

1          keyword1a,keyword1b,keyword1c            6
2                  keyword2a                        6
3                   testing                         5
```

Currently the query I'm using is :

```
select array(select b.keywords from business_objectives b where b.objectivable_id = 6)
```

It selects the keywords of matched objectivable_id as:

```
{"keyword1a,keyword1b,keyword1c","keyword2a"}
```

Over here I wanted the result to be :

```
{"keyword1a","keyword1b","keyword1c","keyword2a"}
```

I tried using "string_agg(text, delimiter)", but it just combines all the keywords into one single pocket of an array.

Comment: Could you also show the relevant data from `b`?

Comment: @Evert I have updated my question.

Comment: What is the type of the keywords column? An array of text?

Comment: No. Its text only

Comment: In that case, the single keyword for id 1 is simply that: three words separated by a comma. They may be stored incorrectly, but currently, that *is* the keyword. If you want to separate the keywords by comma, I'd suggest you either change the column type to an array of text, or handle the string splitting outside the SQL/database, in a post-processing program. I would avoid using (Postgre)SQL for text processing.

Comment: You *need* to provide your version of Postgres and table definitions showing data types and constraints with your questions. It's essential for this one.

Comment: @Erwin Have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply (and cheaply!) use:

```
SELECT string_to_array(string_agg(keywords, ','), ',')
FROM   business_objectives
WHERE  objectivable_id = 6;
```

Concatenate your comma separate lists with `string_agg()`, and then convert the complete text to an array with `string_to_array()`.

Answer (score 1):

So something like this can give you expected result:

```
SELECT  array_agg( j.keys )
FROM    business_objectives b,
LATERAL (   SELECT  k
            FROM    unnest ( string_to_array( b.keywords, ',' ) ) u( k )
        ) j( keys )
WHERE   b.objectivable_id = 6;

                 array_agg
-------------------------------------------
 {keyword1a,keyword1b,keyword1c,keyword2a}
(1 row)
```

With the LATERAL part, we look at the outer query to create a new view. Simply it does split of your *keywords* as set of rows which you can then feed into *array_agg()* function.

See more about LATERAL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL